# Casting generic objects back to the original object in C#

Tags: c#, casting

I having trouble casting from a generic back to the original object in C#

```
private static bool OpenForm<T>( )
{
    List<T> list = FormManager.GetListOfOpenForms<T>();
    if ( list.Count == 0 )
    {
        // not opened
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        // opened
        foreach ( T f in list )
        {
            T ff = ( T ) Convert.ChangeType( f, typeof( T ) );
```

if I type ff. and intellisense pops up with the just a few methods and properties.

how can I have a variable here where it exposes all properties and methods of ff

```
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: f is already T, why you have to convert to T again?

Comment: @CuongLe i am having trouble seeing all the properties etc of f in intellisense

Comment: @trailerman: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: @zerkms I get the contraints bit, but I could be passing many types of form as T to this function, does this mean I would need to constraint to all the types forms I expect to pass to the function??

Comment: @trailerman: if all those classes are of the same hierarchy - use `where T: <base class name>`, if they aren't in the same hierarchy - you just cannot do that

Comment: @trailerman You would constrain the method to the most specific *base type*. If you don't have one, I suggest you extract and implement an interface with the relevant parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it is a generic method, `T` could literally be any type, down to a simple `object`. The compiler - and likewise the intellisense engine - has no idea what `T` is until runtime. Note that this is of course the behavior you want, and it is the reason you use generics in the first place. In this case, using static typing, there is no way to access the members of `T` outside of reflection.

Now what I believe you are looking for is a constraint, that is to say that all `T`s will *always* be of a certain base type. For example, if all `T`s will be `Form`s, you can put a constraint on the method and then access the members of `Form`:

```
private static bool OpenForm<T>() where T : Form
{
    List<T> list = FormManager.GetListOfOpenForms<T>();
    if ( list.Count == 0 )
    {
        // not opened
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        // opened
        foreach ( T f in list )
        {
            f.Text = "You found me!";
        }
    }
}
```

Note I have omitted your conversion from `T f` to `T ff` since it would do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

if T has some sort of common base class(common type), use generic constraints so that the compiler will know that at minimum T will support the methods on the common class. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx